# Creating a polygon with four coordiates?

Tags: c#, sharpmap

I need to draw polygon shape with the following coordiantes

```
private List<IGeometry> geos2 = new List<IGeometry>();
  var gf = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 3857);
                cor1 = new Coordinate(16144349.4032217,-4291402.04717672);
                corner2 = new Coordinate(16145538.9946882,-4291401.77806892);
                corner3 = new Coordinate(16145967.1248121,-4292444.80890257);
                corner4 = new Coordinate(16145352.7123475,-4292584.54329502);
                corner5 = new Coordinate(1500000, 1500000);
```

I tried with following line of code to draw

```
 geos2.Add(gf.CreatePolygon(new Coordinate[] { cor1, corner2, corner3, corner4 }));
```

But noting happening . but i could create Point with the following code

```
geos2.Add(gf.CreatePoint( corner2));
```

Could you please tell me how to make a polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code in the NTS and it should raise an argument exception with the following message: "points must form a closed linestring".

To correct this simply repeat the first point at the end of the coordinate array.

```
geos2.Add(gf.CreatePolygon(new Coordinate[] { cor1, corner2, corner3, corner4, cor1 }));
```

**EDIT**

Well, it's late, but i've made a working test and, maybe, could help someone. In my case, I haven't needed to define the polygon color, it's automatically rendered in black.

```
try
{
    List<GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry> geoms = new List<GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometry>();
    var gf = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 3857);
    var cor1 = new Coordinate(16144349.4032217, -4291402.04717672);
    var corner2 = new Coordinate(16145538.9946882, -4291401.77806892);
    var corner3 = new Coordinate(16145967.1248121, -4292444.80890257);
    var corner4 = new Coordinate(16145352.7123475, -4292584.54329502);
    geoms.Add(gf.CreatePolygon(new Coordinate[] { cor1, corner2, corner3, corner4, cor1 }));

    SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer vlay = new SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("test");
    vlay.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(geoms);
    this.mapBox1.Map.Layers.Add(vlay);

    mapBox1.Map.ZoomToExtents();
    mapBox1.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but its is not showing any polygon on the map

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you, coordinates are sample and it is based on a shape file. after run this code it will create you a polygon layer but the main notice is that the last point should be the first point and the result is a triangle.

```
var myCoordinate1 = new Coordinate(51, 35);
var myCoordinate2 = new Coordinate(54.5, 35.8);
var myCoordinate3 = new Coordinate(52, 33);
    Coordinate[] myCoordinate_P = new Coordinate[] { myCoordinate1, myCoordinate2, myCoordinate3, myCoordinate1 };

    var gf = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326); //3857

    //Adds a static layer
    var staticLayer = new VectorLayer("Polygon_1");
    //position = geom.GetCentroid();
    var aux = new List<IGeometry>();
    aux.Add(gf.CreatePolygon(myCoordinate_P));

    //staticLayer.Style.Line.Color = Color.Red;

    var geoProviderFixed = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(aux);
    staticLayer.DataSource = geoProviderFixed;

    this.mapBox1.Map.Layers.Add(staticLayer);
    this.mapBox1.Refresh();
```